# Making MS-Excel responsive during the initial calculate workbook operation

Tags: c#, vba, excel, asynchronous

If a large excel sheet containing loads of custom formulas is opened with the calculation mode set as 'automatic', it makes excel unresponsive for a considerable time period while excel calculates all the formulas. Is there anyway to pass the control to the user while the calculations are being done by excel ? Can we deploy an asynchronous call here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate recalculation during opening file (`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`).

Then you have to write function to recalculate i.e. Sheet by Sheet (see `Range.Calculate`) but I'm not sure how you will interact with user -> How inform user that all calculations are done/in progress.